# How to get R.drawable.{var} dynamically from within the Adapter class?

Tags: android, kotlin

Maybe there is an easier way but I was hoping to load the flag images based on what the API is sending me. In this case `server.flag` is "de" for Germany. And I have a `de.png` in drawables which can be accessed via `R.drawable.de`. So I was hoping to do this dynamically.

```
class ServerAdapter(private var serverList: ArrayList<ServerRow>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DefaultViewHolder>() {


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DefaultViewHolder, position: Int) {

            ...

            val id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(server.flag, "drawable", holder.itemView.context.packageName)
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
                .load(id)
                .into(holder.getImage(R.id.server_country_flag_id))

}
}
```

However I get a `Unable to find resource ID #0x0`. id shows as 0.
What am I missing, please?

Comment: Could you provide your adapter's layout as well as your view-holder class?

Comment: Sure, do you mean `DefaultViewHolder`? And what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
val context = holder.itemView.context
int resourceID = context.resources.getIdentifier(
    server.flag, "drawable", context.packageName
)
```

Though, as getIdentifer method is expensive, I wouldn't recommend to do this in onBindViewHolder. Can't you make this conversion before sending the data to the adapter?

Comment: Ah yes the mistake was in `Resources.getSystem()`. It makes sense thank you. You have a point about the performance. I have to think about it.

Comment: Keep a Map<String,Drawable> with your server.flag as key and the drawable as value. You could even do a Map<String,Int> and just keep the resourceID as value.
Check if you already have server.flag in the map, if not run getIdentifier and put it in the map.